# Does the NodeJS xpath library support XPath query expressions?

Tags: xml, node.js, xpath

I'm trying to perform some XPath queries using the NodeJS library but can't find any documentation or examples on what I am trying to do.

Basically, I have a node that has multiple children, some of them named "stringProp".  I am trying to grab only stringProp nodes that have a "name" attribute set at "comment".  Is this possible with the xpath library?

Right now my code, which is getting a parse exception, looks like this:

`var comment = xpath.select("./stringProp/[@name = 'comment']", children[i]);`

This is trying to emulate a similar namespace operation in the xpath library documentation:

`var node = xpath.select("//*[local-name(.)='title' and namespace-uri(.)='myns/']", doc)[0]`

However, the library documentation does not show any similar examples using attributes.

Comment: I don't know but a google search brought [this](https://npmjs.org/package/xpath) up, [github src](https://github.com/goto100/xpath).

Comment: Thanks.  That is the documentation from which I pasted the line in the question.  It is not very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use this xpath:

```
./stringProp[@name = 'comment']
```

(removed a slash)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This was so long ago I can't remember how I ended up getting around it, but you're probably correct on the trailing slash.